# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

lang.NullPointerException android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java) 
just am adding Arraylist values into customAdapter class and setting that values into listview 
see below code helpm me

thanks

```
private void fetchCallLogsDetails(String selectedId) {
        this.SelectedLogId = selectedId;
        new FetchCallLogDetailsAsyncTask() {
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                if (mCallLogModel.getmPhoto() != null) {
                    mCallLogPhoto.setImageBitmap(mCallLogModel.getmPhoto());
                }

                mCallLogDetailName.setText(mCallLogModel.getmName());
                mCallLogDetailNumber.setText(mCallLogModel.getmNumber());

                mCallLogDetailName.setTextSize(12);
                mCallLogDetailNumber.setTextSize(10);

                mLogAuditUtilList = mCallLogModel.getmLogAuditUtilList();
                if (mLogAuditUtilList != null) {
                    mCallLogAuditArrayAdapter = new CallLogAuditArrayAdapter(
                            getActivity(), R.id.details_audit_log_list,
                            mLogAuditUtilList);

                    mAuditListView.setAdapter(mCallLogAuditArrayAdapter);
                }

            };
        }.execute("");
    }
    class FetchCallLogDetailsAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // reading call logs from contentReslover
            mCallLogUtil = CallLogUtil.newInstance(mconContentResolver);
            mCallLogModel = mCallLogUtil.selectedLogDetails(SelectedLogId);
            return false;
        }

    }



customeAdapter class
-------------------------

public class CallLogAuditArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LogAuditUtil> {
    private LayoutInflater minflater;
    private ImageView mCallTypeImage;

    public CallLogAuditArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<LogAuditUtil> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        minflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final LogAuditUtil mLogAuditUtil = this.getItem(position);

        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.call_logs_details_list_view,
                null);
        TextView mCallType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.call_logs_details_list_view_type_id);
        TextView mDetailsDate = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.call_logs_details_list_view_date_id);
        mCallTypeImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.call_logs_details_list_view_type_image_id);

        TextView mCallDuration = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.call_logs_details_list_view_call_duration_id);

        mCallType.setTextSize(12);
        mDetailsDate.setTextSize(10);
        mCallDuration.setTextSize(8);

        switch (Integer.parseInt(mLogAuditUtil.getmAuditType())) {
        case 1:
            mCallType.setText(R.string.text_incoming_call);
            mCallTypeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.incoming_call);
            break;

        case 2:
            mCallTypeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.outgoing_call);
            mCallType.setText(R.string.text_outgoing_call);
            break;

        case 3:
            mCallTypeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.missed_call);
            mCallType.setText(R.string.text_missed_call);
            break;
        }

        mDetailsDate.setText(mLogAuditUtil.getmAuditDate());
        mCallDuration.setText(mLogAuditUtil.getmAuditDuration());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

when am runing this code am getting blow errors in catlog

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at com.movirtu.contactsUtil.CallLogsArrayAdapter.<init>(CallLogsArrayAdapter.java:30)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at com.movirtu.fragments.CallLogsFragment$2.onPostExecute(CallLogsFragment.java:88)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at com.movirtu.fragments.CallLogsFragment$2.onPostExecute(CallLogsFragment.java:1)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-07 19:58:56.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3047):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 19:58:58.917: I/Process(3047): Sending signal. PID: 3047 SIG: 9
```

Comment: is `getActivity` returning `null`? when you call this code the fragment is attached?

Comment: thanks but i tryed working fine  but when am communicating fragments synchronuslly again same error is coming how to reslove this error

Answer (score 8):

This issue is caused by the fact that the getActivity() is returning null on the time you're creating the Adapter:

```
 new CallLogAuditArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.details_audit_log_list, mLogAuditUtilList);
```

This can happen if the Activity is not yet attached to the fragment, or it has been detached. To solve it you could either ensure that the method **fetchCallLogsDetails** is only called under a valid state of attached activity OR you could ignore the call if **getActivity() == null** or **getActivity.isFinishing()**.

Comment: Sorry if i answer and re open the question now but i have the same problem and i didn't understand how exactly write. so if getActivity() == null i don't start the asynktask?

Comment: you can do it on your onPostExecute()...for instance: stop the execution of the onPostExecute() if getActivity == null OR getActivity.isFinishing() == true... this is because the result of the onPostExecute() comes asynchronously and by the time it comes it might be possible that the activity was detached OR destroyed (either because the user rotated the device OR pressed back key).

Comment: This is my adapter if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574733/asynktask-nullpointerexception-pressing-back-button thank you.

Comment: basically you have to put the code of the onPostExecute() inside a if(getActivity() != null)...to prevent cases like rotating screen..BUT where do you start your asynctask? where do you call the logo.execute()? You have to respect the lifecycle of the fragment..for instance, you should call it on the onActivityCreated OR onResume()..not on the Fragment.onCreate() because at this point the activity is not attached yet..therefore getActivity() will always be NULL.

Comment: mmh, i call it in the onCreate()... so do you think that if i just call the asynktask in onResume() could be a solution? i didn't notice that.. Thanks.

Comment: i would recommend you to call it on the onActivityCreated() of the fragment..so it won't happen every time the activity resumes...BUT the onResume() would also work great.

Comment: Oh sorry i'm going crazy.. yes i call that in the onActivityCreated() already. Sorry.. But not in onResume(). So it's better in both?

Comment: only on the onActivityCreated() it should be fine at this point the getActivity() is no longer null. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575333/684582