# getActivity returning null from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

For school I am making an android app. For this app I have a fragment, which shows a gridview with just strings, from a database. For this I need a fragment. When I call getActivity(), it returns null. The onAttach method, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function) doesn't get called before the app crashes. How should I solve this?
weekFragmetn.xml:

```
package nl.siebeh.schoolmate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class weekFragment extends Fragment {
    dbLayer db;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mContext = getActivity();
        Log.i("Schoolmate","onAttach called");
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    public weekFragment newInstance(String title) {
        Log.i("Schoolmate","newInstance called");
        db = new dbLayer(mContext);
        weekFragment fragment = new weekFragment();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> result = null;

        if(title == "leraren"){
            result = db.getAllRowsAsArrays("weekTeacher", null);
        }else if(title == "locatie"){
            result = db.getAllRowsAsArrays("weekLocation", null);
        }else if(title == "vakken"){
            result = db.getAllRowsAsArrays("weekSubjects", null);
        }

        String[] array = new String[60];

        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
            array[i] = "";
        }

        array[1] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days)[0];
        array[2] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days)[1];
        array[3] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days)[2];
        array[4] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days)[3];
        array[5] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days)[4];

        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            array[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        }

        for(int position = 0; position < result.size(); position++){
            ArrayList<Object> row = result.get(position);
            int hour = Integer.valueOf(row.get(1).toString()).intValue();
            int day =  Integer.valueOf(row.get(0).toString()).intValue();
            int pos = 6 * hour + day;
            array[pos] = row.get(position).toString();
        }
        fragment.mContent = array;

        return fragment;
    }

    private String[] mContent = {""};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.week_fragment, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new weekAdapter(mContext, mContent));
        return gridview;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }



}
```

logcat: (since click on the item the item in a list that starts the activity, where the fragment is started/embedded)

```
    09-29 19:10:56.611: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { cmp=nl.siebeh.schoolmate/.overviewWeek } from pid 536
09-29 19:10:56.970: INFO/Schoolmate(536): newInstance called
09-29 19:11:06.631: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
09-29 19:11:06.671: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40770188 nl.siebeh.schoolmate/.overviewWeek}
09-29 19:12:20.661: DEBUG/SntpClient(70): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-29 19:14:11.811: DEBUG/dalvikvm(536): Debugger has detached; object registry had 413 entries
09-29 19:14:11.811: ERROR/SchoolMate(536): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 19:14:11.811: INFO/SchoolMate(536): Context is null
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.dbLayer.<init>(dbLayer.java:50)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.weekFragment.newInstance(weekFragment.java:31)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.fragmentAdapter.getItem(fragmentAdaptar.java:21)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.titleFragmentAdapter.getItem(titleFragmentAdapter.java:1)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:62)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:321)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:441)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(ViewPager.java:563)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:6156)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1122)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.820: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:765)
09-29 19:14:11.830: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
09-29 19:14:11.840: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 19:14:11.840: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 19:14:11.840: WARN/System.err(536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-29 19:14:11.840: WARN/System.err(536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 19:14:11.840: WARN/System.err(536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 19:14:11.850: WARN/System.err(536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-29 19:14:11.850: WARN/System.err(536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-29 19:14:11.850: WARN/System.err(536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 19:14:11.850: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(536): Shutting down VM
09-29 19:14:11.850: WARN/dalvikvm(536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.weekFragment.newInstance(weekFragment.java:49)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.fragmentAdapter.getItem(fragmentAdaptar.java:21)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at nl.siebeh.schoolmate.titleFragmentAdapter.getItem(titleFragmentAdapter.java:1)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:62)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:321)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:441)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(ViewPager.java:563)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:6156)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1122)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:765)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-29 19:14:11.870: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 19:14:11.890: WARN/ActivityManager(70):   Force finishing activity nl.siebeh.schoolmate/.overviewWeek
09-29 19:14:12.413: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40770188 nl.siebeh.schoolmate/.overviewWeek}
09-29 19:14:21.910: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
09-29 19:14:22.441: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4070c7a0 nl.siebeh.schoolmate/.schoolmate}
09-29 19:14:32.451: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40770188 nl.siebeh.schoolmate/.overviewWeek}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not ***have*** a `getActivity()` call, which makes it difficult to answer the question.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because `mContext` is `null`. My guess is that `mContext` is `null` because, in the code to `fragmentAdapter`, you are calling `new weekFragment()`, then calling `newInstance()` on it. You presumably thought you were following some patterns outlined in the `Fragment` JavaDocs, but in there, `newInstance()` is a `static` method, not an instance method as you have it here.

Take just about all of the code out of `newInstance()` and move it to `onActivityCreated()` or some time when the fragment is attached to the activity so `getActivity()` works. Along the way, delete your `onAttach()` implementation and the `mContext` data member, neither of which are needed (and the `mContext` is populated in a very scary way).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In onAttach should the mContext be set to getActivity(), What it is now is something I found on another site. I will try it out immediately.

Comment: @Swilzard: "In onAttach should the mContext be set to getActivity()" -- no, just call `getActivity()` when you need the `Activity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare : in my case I am launching fragment on click of button..so here it's assumed activity already created. but now here if call getActivity().finish() from fragment..it's giving NULL POINTER...any suggestion.?

Comment: @Shubh: My suggestion would be to open a fresh StackOverflow question.