# Can't create database manager under Fragment Activity class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am now trying to create new database manager under Fragment class. But unfortunately, I just stuck in the middle of some strage error that i never face with it before. Please have a look at below codes.

```
public class About extends Fragment {
DBManager gDatabase = new DBManager(this);
private AboutInfo ai;
```

The error code is that The constructor DBManage(About) is undefined.
Two quick fix available:

> Change constructor 'DBManager(Context) to 'DBManager(About)''
>   Create constructor 'DBManager(About)'

And here is my database manager codes.

```
public DBManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    DBManager.myContext = context;
}
```

What is wrong with my codes? Any quick help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs an Activity context, not a Fragment context.

Try:

```
DBManager gDatabase = new DBManager(getActivity());
```

Comment: I would suggest passing the `getApplicationContext()` just to ensure that no memory leaks occur :)

Answer (score 1):

use new DBManager(`this.getActivity()`); but in OnCreateView or other function called [after onAttach'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function) as per  [Fragment lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)  ......