# NullPointerException on getActivity() Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently in a `Fragment` I run a normal `Toast.makeText()` command. The command takes time to execute as it is inside a `Volley` operation. During the time that the `Toast` actually does appear the user has time to go back to previous `Fragment`s. If in that situation the user goes back to the previous `Fragment`, a `NullPointerException` occurs.

```
11-28 13:53:53.965: E/AndroidRuntime(22654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 13:53:53.965: E/AndroidRuntime(22654): Process: com.developmentcheck.dcforpublic, PID: 22654
11-28 13:53:53.965: E/AndroidRuntime(22654): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 13:53:53.965: E/AndroidRuntime(22654):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
11-28 13:53:53.965: E/AndroidRuntime(22654):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
```

The code :

```
Toast.makeText(
        getSherlockActivity(),
        "Sorry something went wrong. Please update again.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It is used in the following method(which is called in the `onActivityCreated`):

```
public void castVote(final String id, int vote_state,
        final String situations) throws JSONException {

JsonObjectRequest jsrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        url, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("JSON_RESPONSE_VOTE", response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Your vote was sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getSherlockActivity(),
                        "Sorry something went wrong. Please update again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Please help.

Comment: the only reason is that getSherlockActivity is returning null.

Comment: When and where do you call the `Toast`?

Comment: how can this be resolved ?? I also tried with getActivity(). @blackbelt

Comment: I call the toast in my Volley function ... onResponse() to be exact. @AmulyaKhare

Comment: Does it always happen or only sometimes?

Comment: You might be calling it before the `onAttach()` event of your fragment in which case there is no activity available yet.

Comment: @blackbelt look at the edit

Comment: @SathishKumar look at the edit

Comment: @Ricardo ... How do I know that the `onAttach()` is already executed ?? I am calling it in the `onActivityCreated()` ... Plus the Fragments are inside the `FrameLayout` of the MainActivity, where all the fragments are replaced.

Comment: @user2247689 can you add your onActivityCreated() code here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function?rq=1 check this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a member variable `mPendingToastText` in your fragment class. Then try this:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (getSherlockActivity() != null) {
        Toast.makeText(
            getSherlockActivity(),
            "Sorry something went wrong. Please update again.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
         mPendingToastText = "Sorry something went wrong. Please update again.";
    }

}
```

Now override a `onAttach()` event to your fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mPendingToastText) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    mPendingToastText,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mPendingToastText = "";
    }
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

This code is not a good solution but it should give you an idea of what is happening. Ideally you should have some kind of method that centralizes your toasts. For example you could register a broadcast receiver in your activity and send all your toasts to be processed by it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: rather than using the `getActivity()` or `getSherlockActivity()` ... I in the `onAttach()` declared ... `this.activity = activity;` ... So while calling the Toast ... I declare the `Toast.makeText(activity, ...)` , which works. You could make this as an edit ... I will delete the comment ...and thanks :) the idea came from you.

Comment: Good! I'm glad it worked for you. I think you can leave your comment there. It is a good idea to  do what you said but just remember to set `this.activity = null` on `onDetach()` as well to avoid other exceptions. :)

Answer (score 1):

This simple way:

1. First declare context variable: 
   `private Context context;`
2. In `onCreateView()`:
   `context = container.getContext();`
3. Use it for Toast:
   `Toast.makeText(context, "Your vote was sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

This is get context from container as ViewGroup, so Toast can be shown.

Hope it helps.