# Why is my activity context null in my fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to create a boilerplate fragment. I keep getting a null reference error though when I try to set the LayoutManager of my RecyclerView:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference

Below is the order in which I call to get the error:

**Main.class:**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch(position){
            default:
                return new WhatsNew();
        }
    }
}
```

**WhatsNew.class:**

```
public class WhatsNew extends Base {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        mDataView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);  //<-- Where the null reference is
    }

    @Override
    public void doWork() {

        WhatsNewAdapter mAdapter = new WhatsNewAdapter();
        mDataView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

**Base.class:**

```
public class Base extends Fragment {

    public View mView;
    public RecyclerView mDataView;
    public ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    public Context mContext;

    public Base() { }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity mActivity) {
        mContext = mActivity;
        init();
        doWork();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _i, ViewGroup _vg, Bundle savedInstanceBundle){
        mView = _i.inflate(R.layout.f_base, null);
        mDataView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.data);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)mView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        return mView;
    }

    public void init() { }

    public void doWork() { }

}
```

I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function) that I should override `onAttach(Activity activity)` to make sure that the context isn't null, but from the error, it still seems that it is null. Anyone know why I would be getting this error by chance or have a better suggestion on how I should set up my boilerplate fragment? Sorry if the code looks bad, I am trying to learn use fragments better. :)

Comment: try calling `init()` and `doWork()` in either onCreateView() or `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `mDataView` has not yet been initialized.

`onAttach()` is called before `onCreateView()`. `init()` where you use `mDataView` is called before `mDataView` is initialized in `onCreateView()`.

Postpone the code that needs to access fragment views to `onCreateView()` or later.

Answer (score 1):

`onAttach()` is called before `onCreateView()`.

So mDataView is null at init().

I suggest calling `init()` and `doWork()` at `onViewCreated()`