# deleteDatabse(String) not working android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-sqlite

I have an Activity Med.java having the following code:

```
this.deleteDatabase(db.getDatabaseName());
```

And another activity OrderDetails.java. But in this activity I have to add the class name also:

```
OrderDetails.this.deleteDatabase(db.getDatabaseName());
```

And another activity extending Fragment:

```
getActivity().deleteDatabase(db.getDatabaseName());
```

The first two are working fine. But i want to know why in the second activity I have to add the class name. And the third fragment code, it is not working at all. Please help

Answer (score 0):

its using `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);`

inside a fragment might be when you are calling `getActivity()` then `getActivity() can be null` at that time. refer this [getActivity() returns null in Fragment function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)