# getActivity from fragment return null after restarting app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

After restarting my application,

> *getActivity() returns null in my mainFragment.*

**Workflow:**

When I launch my app, I first start with loginActivity (if not login already), then launch mainActivity.

I got mainFragment attached to my mainActivity. 
If I unlog() (bringing me back to loginActivity and finish the mainActivity), and start again the same worflow, getActivity() from my fragment return null.

When I see the log, when I first launch the app, I can see that my fragment is detached from the activity when I use the unlog() function

I found several similar questions on SO:

- [Android Fragment - getActivity().runOnUiThread returns null when restarting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039257/android-fragment-getactivity-runonuithread-returns-null-when-restarting-app)
- [getActivity() returns null in Fragment function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)

saying this : **then you should not use parent(no longer) Activity in the fragment**

I would like launch a new activity from my fragment when I click on a button, but how can I do this without using parent Activity in the fragment? (*new Intent(this.getActivity(), newActivity.class);* returning NPE cause of the null value from getActivity)

Comment: How many fragments do you have in the Main Activity ?

Comment: I got 5 or 6 fragment, and a fragment manager in my mainActivity. But in my case, I only call 1 fragment, the mainFragment


`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();`

Comment: So now the app crashes while clicking the button which launches another activity using intent?

Comment: When I'm on my main fragment and I clicked on my button to launch the game, (in a new activity, gameActivity). It never crash when it's the first launch, only when I come back in mainActivity after unlog