# App crash after click on a ImageView that setImageDrawable

Tags: java, android

My app crash when:

1. HomeActivity started
2. Navigate to CategoryActivity or Open a DialogFragment that share the same recyclerview viewholder
3. Navigate back to HomeActivity, tap on a ImageView that have setDrawable
4. App crash

**Hereby is the crash code**

```
10-31 07:45:52.811 25005-25005/com.studio.douka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.studio.douka, PID: 25005
          java.lang.NullPointerException
              at
    android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
              at com.studio.douka.PostHolder.setLikeStatus(PostHolder.java:163)
              at
    com.studio.douka.PostDialogFragment$3.onDataChange(PostDialogFragment.java:110)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaie.zza(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaje.zzcta(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh$1.run(Unknown Source)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
              at
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hereby is the codes that make the app crash

**PostHolder.java**

```
public class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private static final String TAG = PostHolder.class.getSimpleName();
    public TextView postTitle;
    public ImageView postImage;
    public TextView postLike;
    public TextView postComment;
    public ImageView gifImage;
    public ImageView BtnPostMenu;
    private static final int POST_TEXT_MAX_LINES = 6;
    public ValueEventListener mLikeListener;
    public ValueEventListener mCommentListener;
    public DatabaseReference mPostRef;
    public ValueEventListener mPostListener;
    private final ImageView mLikeIcon;
    private PostClickListener mListener;

    public enum LikeStatus {LIKED, NOT_LIKED}

    private String authorUID;
    private String photoURL;
    private String postKey;
    private String currentStorageRef;
    private String postText;

    public PostHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        postTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        postImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        postLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_like);
        postComment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_comment);
        mLikeIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_like_icon);
        BtnPostMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_menu_button);
        gifImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gif_image);

        itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_comment_icon).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.showComments();
            }
        });

        mLikeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.toggleLike();
            }
        });

        BtnPostMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup(v);
            }
        });

    }

    public void setPhoto(String url, int width, int height, String isAnimated) {


        GlideUtil.loadImage(url, postImage, width, height, isAnimated, gifImage);
    }

    public void getAuthor(String author) {

        if (author != null) {
            authorUID = author;
        }
    }

    public void getStorageRef(String storageRef) {

        if (storageRef != null) {
            currentStorageRef = storageRef;
        }
    }

    public void getPhotoURL(String picURL) {

        if (picURL != null) {
            photoURL = picURL;
        }
    }

    public void getKey(String key) {

        if (key != null) {
            postKey = key;
        }
    }

    public void getText(String pText) {

        if (pText != null) {
            postText = pText;
        }
    }

    public void setText(final String text) {
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            postTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        } else {
            postTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            postTitle.setText(text);
            postTitle.setMaxLines(POST_TEXT_MAX_LINES);
            postTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (postTitle.length() == POST_TEXT_MAX_LINES) {
                        postTitle.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    } else {
                        postTitle.setMaxLines(POST_TEXT_MAX_LINES);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setNumLikes(long numLikes) {
        String suffix = numLikes == 1 ? " like" : " likes";
        postLike.setText(numLikes + suffix);
    }

    public void setNumComments(long numComments) {
        String suffix = numComments == 1 ? " comment" : " comments";
        postComment.setText(numComments + suffix);
    }

    public void setLikeStatus(LikeStatus status, Context context) {
        mLikeIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                status == LikeStatus.LIKED ? R.drawable.heart_full : R.drawable.heart_empty));
    }

    public void setPostClickListener(PostClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface PostClickListener {
        void showComments();

        void toggleLike();
    }

    public void showPopup(final View v) {

        final String currentUID = FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId();

        if (authorUID.equals(currentUID)) {

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.own_post_menu_popup, popup.getMenu());

            popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_edit).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    showChangeLangDialog(v);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_delete).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(photoURL);

                    storageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                            Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                            childUpdates.put("posts/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("comments/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("likes/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("userNotifications/" + currentUID + "/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("people/" + currentUID + "/" + "posts/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("postCategory/car/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("postCategory/funny/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("postCategory/gaming/" + postKey, null);
                            childUpdates.put("postCategory/girl/" + postKey, null);

                            FirebaseUtil.getBaseRef().updateChildren(childUpdates);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            });

            popup.show();

        } else {

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.post_menu_popup, popup.getMenu());

            popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_report).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Reported,,,", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            popup.show();
        }
    }

    public void showChangeLangDialog(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edt.setText(postText);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //do something with edt.getText().toString();

                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                childUpdates.put("text", edt.getText().toString());

                FirebaseUtil.getPostsRef().child(postKey).updateChildren(childUpdates);
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                //pass
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }

}
```

**PostDialogFragment.java**

```
public class PostDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private String postID = null;
    private OnPostSelectedListener mListener;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter<PostHolder> mAdapter;

    public PostDialogFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("Post");

        postID = getArguments().getString("postID");

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        final List<String> postPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        postPaths.add(postID);

        mAdapter = new FirebasePostQueryAdapter(postPaths,
                new FirebasePostQueryAdapter.OnSetupViewListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSetupView(PostHolder holder, Post post, int position, String postKey) {
                        setupPost(holder, post, position, postKey);
                    }
                });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void setupPost(final PostHolder postViewHolder, final Post post, final int position, final String inPostKey) {
        postViewHolder.setPhoto(post.getFull_url(), post.getImageWidth(), post.getImageHeight(), post.getIsAnimated());
        postViewHolder.setText(post.getText());
        postViewHolder.getAuthor(post.getAuthor().getUid());
        postViewHolder.getPhotoURL(post.getFull_url());
        postViewHolder.getStorageRef(getString(R.string.google_storage_bucket));
        postViewHolder.getText(post.getText());

        final String postKey;
        if (mAdapter instanceof FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) {
            postKey = ((FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) mAdapter).getRef(position).getKey();
            postViewHolder.getKey(((FirebaseRecyclerAdapter) mAdapter).getRef(position).getKey());
        } else {
            postKey = inPostKey;
        }

        ValueEventListener likeListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postViewHolder.setNumLikes(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId())) {
                    postViewHolder.setLikeStatus(PostHolder.LikeStatus.LIKED, getActivity());
                } else {
                    postViewHolder.setLikeStatus(PostHolder.LikeStatus.NOT_LIKED, getActivity());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        FirebaseUtil.getLikesRef().child(postKey).addValueEventListener(likeListener);
        postViewHolder.mLikeListener = likeListener;

        ValueEventListener commentListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postViewHolder.setNumComments(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        FirebaseUtil.getCommentsRef().child(postKey).addValueEventListener(commentListener);
        postViewHolder.mCommentListener = commentListener;

        postViewHolder.setPostClickListener(new PostHolder.PostClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void showComments() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Comment position: " + position);
                mListener.onPostComment(postKey);
            }

            @Override
            public void toggleLike() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Like position: " + position);
                mListener.onPostLike(postKey);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnPostSelectedListener {
        void onPostComment(String postKey);

        void onPostLike(String postKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnPostSelectedListener) {
            mListener = (OnPostSelectedListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnPostSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

}
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, PostFragment.OnPostSelectedListener, PostDialogFragment.OnPostSelectedListener, UploadMethodDialogFragment.OnImageSelectedListener {

    private AlertDialog userDialog;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FeedsPagerAdapter adapter = new FeedsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(PostFragment.newInstance(PostFragment.TYPE_NEW), "NEW");
        adapter.addFragment(PostFragment.newInstance(PostFragment.TYPE_CATEGORY), "CATEGORY");
        adapter.addFragment(PostFragment.newInstance(PostFragment.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), "NOTIFICATIONS");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView navName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_name);
        TextView navEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_email);
        ImageView navProfilePicture = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_picture);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
            String user_name = user.getDisplayName();
            String user_email = user.getEmail();
            Uri pictureURL = user.getPhotoUrl();

            navName.setText("" + user_name);
            navEmail.setText("" + user_email);
            Glide
                    .with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(pictureURL)
                    .into(navProfilePicture);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    class FeedsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public FeedsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostComment(String postKey) {

        if (postKey == null) {
            showAlertDialog("无法连接",
                    "Key : " + postKey, false);
        } else {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            CommentFragment um = new CommentFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("postKey", postKey);
            um.setArguments(args);
            um.show(fm, "Comment");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostLike(final String postKey) {
        final String userKey = FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId();
        final DatabaseReference postLikesRef = FirebaseUtil.getLikesRef();
        postLikesRef.child(postKey).child(userKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // User already liked this post, so we toggle like off.
                    postLikesRef.child(postKey).child(userKey).removeValue();
                } else {
                    postLikesRef.child(postKey).child(userKey).setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateNotification(final String postKey) {
        final String userKey = FirebaseUtil.getCurrentUserId();
        final DatabaseReference notificationRef = FirebaseUtil.getUserNotificationsRef();
        notificationRef.child(userKey).child(postKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put("status", false);
                    result.put("count", 0L);
                    notificationRef.child(userKey).child(postKey).updateChildren(result);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostOpenDialog(final String postKey) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("postID", postKey);
        //set Fragment class Arguments
        PostDialogFragment fragObj = new PostDialogFragment();
        fragObj.setArguments(bundle);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragObj.show(fm, "Post Fragment");
    }

    public void onPicSelected(String filePath) {
        if(filePath!=null){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("filePath", filePath);
            //set Fragment class Arguments
            UploadPictureDialogFragment fragObj = new UploadPictureDialogFragment();
            fragObj.setArguments(bundle);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragObj.show(fm, "上载图片");
        }
    }

    public void userDetails(MenuItem item) {

        // [START subscribe_topics]
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("6biC3YfNUiWpHqmasa4O74KPWwC2");
        // [END subscribe_topics]

        // Log and toast
        String msg = "Subscribed to news topic";
        Log.d("Subscribe", msg);
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void upload_method(MenuItem item) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        UploadMethodDialogFragment um = new UploadMethodDialogFragment();
        um.show(fm, "Upload Method");
    }

    private void showAlertDialog(String title, String body, Boolean status) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(body).setNeutralButton("好的", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {
                    userDialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //
                }
            }
        });
        userDialog = builder.create();
        userDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}
```

I uploaded gif picture as well for better understanding

[App Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x0QO.gif)

Comment: getActivity() returns null because is used at "wrong time"

Comment: what is the code at line no.110 in the file PostDialogFragment.java?

Comment: @X3Btel in the link you provided, i saw that the question is about the user put his code under activity layout instead of fragment layout, for my case im using recyclerview in fragment and load item with a postviewholder, so my problem is the same as the link you provided?

Comment: @Selvin i dont get why i used getActivity wrongly, i will update with more coding for better understanding

Comment: @Swathin postViewHolder.setLikeStatus(PostHolder.LikeStatus.LIKED, getActivity()); is line no.110

Comment: as @Selvin said the getActivity() is causing the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function

Comment: get (and keep) a reference to your activity/context in `onAttach`, then remove the calls to `getActivity` and use your saved reference instead.

Comment: @trooper great! after look at the link you provided i set my onAttach() this way `@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;

        if (context instanceof OnPostSelectedListener) {
            mListener = (OnPostSelectedListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnPostSelectedListener");
        }
    }`, now everything work great after i used saved context to replace getActivity(), thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` provided to `getDrawable()` is null. This means `getActivity()` is returning null which is possible. To avoid that save the activity context in `onAttach()` method of fragment and use that afterwards.

Comment: i got onAttach with context in the code like this

`@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnPostSelectedListener) {
            mListener = (OnPostSelectedListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnPostSelectedListener");
        }
    }`

issue is still seen, without this code the app will crash immediately without any view

Comment: marked this as answer since this is the first correct answer provided