# new Dialog(context) is crashing after updating buildtoolversion from 23 to 25 and minsdkversion from 14 to 15

Tags: android, dialog

Dialog class Snippet:

```
public class Progress {

    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public Progress(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * show the progress bar
     * @return
     */
    public Dialog showProgress() {
        Dialog pDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        pDialog.setContentView(new MaterialProgressBar(mContext), new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    }



    /**
     * dismiss the progress bar
     * @param pDialog
     */
    public void dismissProgress(Dialog pDialog) {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

In Fragment call calling dialog in `onCreatemethod` :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.mContext = getActivity();       
        progress = new Progress(mContext);
    progress.showProgress();
}
```

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
                                                               at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:175)
                                                               at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:149)
                                                               at com.contus.mcomm.views.Progress.showProgress(Progress.java:44)
                                                               at com.contus.mcomm.fragments.ProductListFragment.setUserVisibleHint(ProductListFragment.java:154)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:157)
                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1270)
                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
```

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: show some exception stacktrace...

Comment: i have added exception , please review , any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

SDK update may be not the issue. some times getActivity() returns null. so try to display dialog in onViewCreated() method in fragment.

For more you can check this - 
[getActivity() returns null in Fragment function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)

Comment: i have tried all the methods , but none of them works.

Comment: i think , i am sure that this is happening due to version change , nut not able to find a solution for it.

Comment: i have a class ProductListFragmentImpl extends Fragment { }  and another class extends ProductListFragmentImpl where i need to show dialog.

Comment: i have found that my onAttact is never called in fragment.

Comment: I suggest you debug full code of both class and check weather fragment get attached or not. and if you are loading child fragment then use getChildFragmentManager(). because that will take care of attachment and detachment.

Answer (score 0):

@androidnoobdev pointed right

`getActivity()` might return null in `onCreate`, because `Fragment` may be not attached to any `Activity` at this moment... you should move your code to `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.mContext = getActivity(); //do you really need this?
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    progress = new Progress(getActivity());
    progress.showProgress();
}
```

if it not showing then you are not attaching `Fragment` properly and its parent `Activity` isn't present

there are also two methods:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}
```

first one, with `Activity` as param, was deprecated in API23 and second one was introduced in same API version. you may also move your dialog creation code here