# getPackageName() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, icons

I was using this method to resize markers in a Google Maps activity:

```
public Bitmap resizeMapIcons(String iconName,int width, int height){
    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, width, height, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Now I wanted to use it in a fragment with MapView, but I get the error "error: cannot find symbol method getPackageName()".
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this instead of getPackageName()

```
getActivity().getPackageName()
```

Comment: I don't use getPackageManager(), I use getPackageName(). But it works with getActivity().getPackageName(). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. getPackageName() is correct!

Answer (score 6):

## `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`

---

The easiest way is probably:

```
String PkgName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

---

Notes:

- You can access `BuildConfig` from anywhere on your code.
- Doesn't work on libraries

Answer (score 5):

Here's to get package name for Kotlin in a Fragment

`context!!.packageName`

Answer (score 3):

```
getPackageName()
```

is defined in Activity . you can not directly use it in your `Fragment`. Try use:

```
    if(getActivity()!=null){
         Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));
         //rest of your code
   }
```

It is best practice to check if getActivity is null or not. So your app will not crash.Read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)

You can also create a static variable in your main activity, instantiated to be the package name. Then just use that variable in fragment.

```
    public static String PACKAGE_NAME;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}
```

Now you can access it using:

```
MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME
```

Comment: And how can I put the if statement in the method? I don't want to use static variables, because this way I can use this method for different bitmaps.

Comment: My problem is that if I close the end statement before the return I can't use the resizedBitmap variable, but if I close it after the return, than the method misses the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get PackageManager in `Fragment` onCreateView()

```
view.getContext().getPackageName()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

Add this somewhere in your code:

```
val Fragment.packageName get() = activity?.packageName
```

And then simply use packageName directly in your Fragment code

```
val name = packageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
requireActivity().getPackageName()
```