# Android start Activity From Fragment Crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I am trying this code to start a activity from a Fragment by adding this code but the app crashes here

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), IsActive.class);
startActivity(i);
getActivity().finish();
```

this is my error log :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                        Process: media.aer.influencer, PID: 16165
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4459)
  at media.aer.influencer.Activity.MarkAsActiveFragment$10.onResponse(MarkAsActiveFragment.java:396)
  at media.aer.influencer.Activity.MarkAsActiveFragment$10.onResponse(MarkAsActiveFragment.java:333)
  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
  at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: This one, in particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/27678112/2308683

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are dealing with fragments then you should use getContext() to get the Activity.

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), IsActive.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: What about `getActivity().finish()`?

Comment: In some cases the getActivity() will return null or gives error in that case avoid call of `finish()` .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getActivity()`

Use `YourActivityName.getActivity();`

in both the places

Like

```
private HomeActivity csActivity;
csActivity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
```

so you can use `csActivity` instead of `getActivity()`

Comment: How does storing the Activity reference help? That's just going to cause a memory leak

Comment: try to use getContext()

Comment: Are you guessing?

Comment: getContext() i am guessing

Comment: Declare your Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), IsActive.class);
           startActivity(i);
           getActivity().finish(); in main activity class and call function from your fragemets coool

Comment: getActivity() isn't a method in the Activity class

Comment: then use youractivity.this in activity classs