# converting a activity to fragment it shows some errors on array adapter

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
    listViewIp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewip);
    bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbar);
    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ipList = new ArrayList();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ipList);
    listViewIp.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ScanIpTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

convert it to fragment

ArrayList ipList;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scan_ip, container, false);

    btnScan = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.scan);
    listViewIp = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listviewip);
    bar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbar);
    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ipList = new ArrayList();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ipList);
    listViewIp.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ScanIpTask().execute();
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

it shows error in this line

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ipList);

Comment: What is error??

Comment: See the answer below . And do not just rename the class name . First read the classes you are using . `Activity` and `Fragment` are way too different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code with

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ipList);
```

Comment: Thanks For The Help

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` constructor's first argument is `Context`. And `Fragment`
 is not a child of `Context`.  You need to pas the `Context` of the parent `Activity`.

> ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)

Use `getActivity()` to get the context of parent Activity.

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ipList);
listViewIp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`getActivity()` inside `onCreateView()` can return null sometimes cause fragment not attached yet. To clear the concept pls read [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function) or similar.