# Custom dialog interface for multiple Activities/ Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, dialog

I am new to android studio and I am trying implement a dialogfragment to pop up whenever a button is clicked or a toolbar action_add button is clicked. It sends data from the dialog box to a fragment or an activity (trying to understand how it works for both). My dialog class has an interface, which worked great when I implemented it in the fragment, but the activity is a bit different. I am using the interface to pass the data to the activity, then I am using Bundle to transfer the data from the activity to the fragment. I believe the error occurs in the onAttach since I have getTargetFragment();

Is it possible to have multiple activities/fragments implement a single interface? If so, how do I cater to both the activity and fragment in the interface, onAttach, and the sending of data?

Thank you guys in advance, below is my code for the custom_dialog class for the dialogbox, and a fragment which is attached to an activity. The goal is either press the button in the fragment or the toolbar on the activity to open a dialog and get an input from the user, that will be transferred to be displayed.

Error:

```
Process: com.example.andrewg.dialogfragment, PID: 13335
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.andrewg.dialogfragment.MyCustomDialog$OnInputSelected.sendInput(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.andrewg.dialogfragment.MyCustomDialog$2.onClick(MyCustomDialog.java:58)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25881)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
MyCustomDialog.OnInputSelected{

public String dialogInput;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
public void sendInput(String input) {
    dialogInput = input;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu, this adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    //Redundant
    MenuItem actionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add);
    actionMenuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new 
MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //Handle action bar clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the home/up button
    //so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml

    switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_add:
            MyCustomDialog dialog = new MyCustomDialog();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");

            //Trying to pass dialog input into an intent to send to the 
fragment
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
MainFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra("Dialog Input", dialogInput);
            startActivity(intent);*/
            //Trying Bundle to pass data, dialog input between activity and 
fragment
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Dialog Input", dialogInput);
            //Set Fragment class arguments
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle); //set argument bundle to fragment

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainFragment,fragment).commit(); //now replace Mainfragment


            Toast.makeText(this, "Action_Add Clicked Successfully", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements 
MyCustomDialog.OnInputSelected{

TextView InputDisplay;
Button OpenDialog;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    InputDisplay = view.findViewById(R.id.InputDisplay);
    OpenDialog = view.findViewById(R.id.Open_Dialog);

    //Getting Main Activity dialog information with Bundle, that was received from toolbar add
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        String dialogInput = bundle.toString();
        InputDisplay.setText(dialogInput);
    }
    //String dialogInput = this.getArguments().getString("Dialog Input");

    OpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("MainFragment", "onClick: opening dialog");

            MyCustomDialog customDialog = new MyCustomDialog();
            customDialog.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this, 1);
            customDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyCustomDialog");
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void sendInput(String input) {
    InputDisplay.setText(input);
}
}
```

Custom Dialog: I added a second interface variable for activity for onAttach to use getActivity(), but it doesn't seem right.

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

private EditText Input;
private TextView ActionOK, ActionCANCEL;

public OnInputSelected onInputSelected_Fragment;
public OnInputSelected onInputSelected_Activity;

public interface OnInputSelected{
    void sendInput(String input);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    try{
        onInputSelected_Fragment = (OnInputSelected) getTargetFragment();
        onInputSelected_Activity = (OnInputSelected) getActivity();
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        Log.e("Custom Dialog", "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_my_custom, container, false);

    Input = view.findViewById(R.id.Input);
    ActionOK = view.findViewById(R.id.Action_OK);
    ActionCANCEL = view.findViewById(R.id.Action_CANCEL);

    ActionCANCEL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    ActionOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onInputSelected_Fragment.sendInput(Input.getText().toString());
            onInputSelected_Activity.sendInput(Input.getText().toString());

            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. It's easier to answer them separately. And future readers will have a better chance of finding exactly what they are looking for. My suggestion: ask a new question about your second problem because most of the text/ the code snippet belongs to the first problem.

Comment: Alright I edited it to just have my primary question

Comment: The NPE does not occur in `onAttach()` because you can read in the Logcat "at com.example.andrewg.dialogfragment.MyCustomDialog$2.onClick(MyCustomDialog.java:58)". So it's happening during the execution of some  `onClick()` method. Which line is line 58?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple activities/fragments implement a single interface?

Yes it is. You just have to be aware that `getActivity()` will return `null` if the `DialogFragment` is not attached to an `Activity` but to another `Fragment` whereas `getTargetFragment()` will return `null` if there is no target `Fragment`, e.g. when you show the dialog directly from your `Activity` and so did not call `setTargetFragment()`.

Since casting `null` to anything does not result in an `Exception`, all you have to do in your code is a `null` check before actually calling an interface method.

But because you will not have a target `Fragment` and an `Activity` showing the same instance of your `DialogFragment`, you can change your code and do with just one field

```
private OnInputSelected onInputSelected;
```

Then in `onAttach()` you check which one is null - `Activity` or target `Fragment` - and set `onInputSelected` correctly once and for all.

```
try{
    Fragment onInputSelected_Fragment = getTargetFragment();
    Activity onInputSelected_Activity = getActivity();
    if (onInputSelected_Fragment != null){
        onInputSelected = (OnInputSelected)onInputSelected_Fragment;
    }
    else {
        onInputSelected = (OnInputSelected)onInputSelected_Activity;
    }
    // throw RuntimeException here if onInputSelected still is null
    //
}catch(ClassCastException e){
    Log.e("Custom Dialog", "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Note that `onInputSelected` might be null if you forgot to set a target `Fragment` when showing the dialog from a Fragment. This would be a programming error, so maybe you want to throw a `RuntimeException` in this case. If your app makes it past this point, you have something implementing the interface, mission accomplished.

In your `onClick()` you can simply write

```
onInputSelected.sendInput(Input.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks nosugar, that worked nicely. Could you take a look at my how I'm retrieving my bundle in MainFragment. It displays as "Bundle[{Dialog Input = hello}] where hello is the input. And it only updates when I like the actionbar for the second time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() is returning null.  According to [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function) the getActivity() will return null until after onAttach is run.  If you move super.onAttach() to the beginning of your onAttach method then it should return the activity correctly.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        onInputSelected_Fragment = (OnInputSelected) getTargetFragment();
        onInputSelected_Activity = (OnInputSelected) getActivity();
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        Log.e("Custom Dialog", "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```