# getActivity null exception warning?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment where I'll do the following:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                }
                    });
```

Here I get for `runOnUiThread` a warning `may produce NullPointerException`.
The code works without problems.Android Studio suggests I change the code like this:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
```

is that sensible ? is there any other/better way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what your objective is :

**1)** You want the method caller to know he made a mistake by calling this method at a wrong state where `getActivity()`

```
private void myMethod() {
    if(null == getActivity()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Trying to call getActivity() at a state where the Activity equals null"); // Or new NullPointerException("")
    }
    // Do your stuff with getActivity()
}
```

**2)** You know that `getActivity()` will not throw a `NullPointerException` in your case :

```
private void myMethod() {
    assert getActivity() != null;
    // Do your stuff with getActivity()
}
```

**3)** You know that `getActivity()` may be null, you don't want the app to suddenly stop :

```
private void myMethod() {
    if(null == getActivity()) {
        return;
    }
    // Do your stuff with getActivity()
}
```

Using Objects.requireNonNull() also requires api level 19 (4.4 (KITKAT))

You also have tons of information right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function/27678112)

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a null check, which may be more understandable.

```
if(getActivity() != null) {
      getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                                }
        });
}
```

But also, you can use the method #requireActivity()
This works as a getActivity but if the activity is null (if the fragment is detached) it will throw an IllegalStateException

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#requireActivity()

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** Use Flag `isAdded`(fragment is added to host activity) before `getActivity()`. This helps to avoid null pointer exception if the fragment is detached from the host activity.

```
if (isAdded() && null != getActivity()) {
   // your logic
}
```

**(2)** `requireNonNull(T obj)` Checks that the specified object reference is not null. This method is designed primarily for doing parameter validation in methods and constructors.

Throws `NullPointerException` - if obj is `null`(*application execution may terminate at this point*).

**Summary**: As per your current context `requireNonNull(T obj)` is not suitable. You must handle `null` pointer gracefully.