# nullpointerexception in getResource method

Tags: java, android

When I click back button in my app, I get a NullPointerException in getResource() method. getResource is used in the url and is called in the glideApp.

my code

```
private void setupPostUserImage(ImageView image, PostDetail detail) {
    mUserPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String url = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.profile_image_path1) + "/" + detail.getUser_id_fk() + "/thumb/" + detail.getProfile_picture();
    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    GlideApp.with(image.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_avtar_male)
            .into(image);
}
```

This is my crash report from logcat

```
Process: com.ATG.World, PID: 24491
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at com.ATG.World.fragments.ArticleDetailFragment2.setupPostUserImage(ArticleDetailFragment2.java:316)
    at com.ATG.World.fragments.ArticleDetailFragment2.setData(ArticleDetailFragment2.java:301)
    at com.ATG.World.fragments.ArticleDetailFragment2$1.onResponse(ArticleDetailFragment2.java:176)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:898)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6716)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-21 19:38:17.829 24491-24491/com.ATG.World I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24491 SIG: 9
```

what should I do in order to resolve this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I went through this but cannot find solution for my problem.

Comment: Sounds like your `getActivity()` is returning null because your fragment was destroyed

Comment: Your code have possibility of breaking at every dot( . ). If getActivity() is null it breaks. If  getActivity().getResources() is null it breaks. So before using dot operator on any object do a null check and then access the object / function.

Comment: @MukeshVerma null check worked for me. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment so I have to write answer. It looks like your fragment is not attached to activity so method getActivity() returns null. Look this answer may be it will be useful [getActivity() returns null in Fragment function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)